# pyside/pyqt: when converting str() to QTreeWidgetItem() the str() is shortened to the [0] of str()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

```
s = 'someString'
s = QTreeWidgetItem(s)
print(s.text(0))           # 0 being 'column'
```

Output:

```
's'
```

It also appears as 's' if I run 'addChild(s)' to another QTreeWidgetItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QTreeWidgetItem` construct](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTreeWidgetItem.html#PySide.QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem) is meant to be passed multiple strings (not a single one):

```
>>> s = QTreeWidgetItem(['someString', 'otherString'])
>>> print(s.text(0))
someString
>>> print(s.text(1))
otherString
```

Passing a single string object `'someString'` is like passing a sequence with multiple single-character strings `['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']`.

If you want pass a single string, wrap in list or tuple:

```
s = QTreeWidgetItem(['someString'])
```

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks for the quick response!